# Why is this simple SQL query causing major lag on a simple 6k record table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, debugging, query-optimization

So I have 2 tables, one called `user`, and one called `user_favorite`. `user_favorite` stores an `itemId` and `userId`, for storing the items that the user has favorited. I'm simply trying to locate the users who **don't** have a record in `user_favorite`, so I can find those users who haven't favorited anything yet.

For testing purposes, I have 6001 records in `user` and 6001 in `user_favorite`, so there's just one record who doesn't have any favorites.

Here's my query:

```
  SELECT u.* FROM user u
   JOIN user_favorite fav ON u.id != fav.userId
   ORDER BY id DESC
```

Here the `id` in the last statement is not ambigious, it refers to the id from the `user` table. I have a PK index on `u.id` and an index on `fav.userId`.

When I run this query, my computer just becomes unresponsive and completely freezes, with no output ever being given. I have 2gb RAM, not a great computer, but I think it should be able to handle a query like this with 6k records easily.

Both tables are in MyISAM, could that be the issue? Would switching to INNODB fix it?

Comment: Inner join with negation; interesting...  Have you tried this without the `order by` and in a smaller subset.  Also what does the `explain` of that query look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first discuss what your query (as written) is doing. Because of the != in the on-clause, you are joining every user record with every one of the other user's favorites. So your query is going to produce something like 36M rows. This is not going to give you the answer that you want. And it explains why your computer is unhappy.

How should you write the query? There are three main patterns you can use. I think this is a pretty good explanation: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/ and discusses performance specifically in the context of mysql. And it shows you how to look at and read an execution plan, which is critical to optimizing queries.

Answer (score 1):

change your query to something like this:

```
select * from User 
where not exists (select * from user_favorite where User.id = user_favorite.userId)
```

let me know how it goes

Answer (score 1):

A join on `A != B` means that every record of A is joined with every record of B in which the id's aren't equal.

In other words, instead of producing 6000 rows, you're producing approximately 36 million (6000 * 6001) rows of output, which all have to be collected, then sorted...

Comment: @vinodadhikary: Thanks. I've never taken an official IQ test, so I'm not sure.

Comment: interesting. any solution?

Comment: @ClickUpvote: I've usually used pretty much the same query as Amireza shows. I guess there are other ways, but that generally works all right.